# The layout required to put 3 buttons in the whole scree

Tags: android

I want to know which layout that will allow me to put 3 buttons in the android screen where each button take 1/3 of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your requirement. Let us know what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

a `LinearLayout`. It has the `layout_weight` attribute. If you set each button the same value, every button will take the same space. So you have three buttons and each has `layout_weight = "1"`, they will take 1/3 of the screen each

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button3" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: Instead of putting only code, try to explain why and what the codes does.

Answer (score 1):

Linear Layout can easily let you what you want

For Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1"/>
     <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"/>
      <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Weights assign to each button allow your button to take that much of space which should occupy on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve it using `TableRow`.

```
<TableRow
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"        
       .../>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"        
       .../>

  <Button
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"        
       .../>

 </TableRow>
```

And of course using `LinearLayout` as other answers suggests.